# resizing GtkPaned widget in glade

Tags: gtk, glade

I want to design a Gtk UI in glade.
I need a window which has 3 resizable columns which I used GtkPaned container to create that.
The problem is that resizing left column also resizes the right column (and vice versa). I don't want that, I want to resize a column and the other columned stays fixed. I couldn't find a way to do that in glade.

here is my gladefile content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.36.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.22"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkPaned">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="resize">False</property>
            <property name="shrink">True</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkPaned">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkEntry">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="resize">False</property>
                <property name="shrink">True</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="resize">True</property>
                <property name="shrink">True</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="resize">True</property>
            <property name="shrink">True</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: Have you tried playing with the `expand` and `resize` properties of the GtkPaned children?

Comment: @theGtknerd yes, I changed those properties but didn't work the way I want